# Chrome app: "This application is not supported on this computer"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

This is how the app shows in Chrome Webstore:

[image: Webstore screenshot]

> This application is not supported on this computer. Installation has been disabled. The following problems are detected:
>
> - This app runs only on Chrome OS

This is my manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "AppName",
  "version": "3",
   "author":"AuthorName",
   "description":"Simple app",

  "icons": {
      "16":"public/app_logo.png",
      "22":"public/app_logo.png",
      "32":"public/app_logo.png",
      "48":"public/app_logo.png",
      "128":"public/app_logo.png"
  },
  "permissions": ["storage"],
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: This is a chrome [app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps). Chrome apps in WebStore can be installed [only on ChromeOS](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html).

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Apps are [deprecated](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html) on all platforms except ChromeOS.

> In the second half of 2017, the Chrome Web Store will no longer show Chrome apps on Windows, Mac, and Linux, but will continue to surface extensions and themes. **In early 2018, users on these platforms will no longer be able to load Chrome apps.**

You can try to replicate some of the app functionality using Progressive Web Apps, but it's certainly more limited than Chrome Apps API.

Comment: Thanks, I have uploaded it as an extension.

Comment: ..or an extension, yes. That's also OK if the API provided is enough.

Comment: Hello, I have developed a Chrome App that can be installed manually, but when I published it and then tried to install, the same message here appeared. This App uses socket connection, so I cannot move it to an extension. How can I do it without needing to change everything? I created a Chrome App because I need to send some data from a Web page to a native Windows application by mean of a TCP/IP connection to localhost.

Comment: @jstuardo You can't do it without needing to change everything. An extension can still talk over HTTP with localhost, including WebSockets - just not raw sockets. If you control the native component, you need to reengineer for that. If you don't, well.. You could make another one as a "transport layer". There's also Native Messaging but that again needs either changes to backend or a translation layer.